# storing stuff into a variable size structure

Tags: c, arrays, string, iteration, structure

I have a follow up question to something I asked a couple of days ago. I have a variable length structure,

```
typedef struct
{
    int *positions1, *positions2; 
    char *symbols, *args; 
    char (*names)[100];     
} agentInfo;

int initStruct(agentInfo *ai, int x)
{
     ai-> positions1 = malloc(x * sizeof(int));
     ai-> positions2 = malloc(x * sizeof(int));
     ai-> symbols = malloc(x);
     ai-> args = malloc(x);
     ai-> names = malloc(100 * x);
     return 0;
}
```

Which I call and create an instance of (mystruct). And I want to read stuff into it each array so that I can access it using an index. I was thinking something like,

```
int a, b; 
char c, d; 
char e[100]; 
char buffer[100]; 

while(fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL){
    if(sscanf(buffer, "%d %d %c %s %c", &a, &b, &c, e, &d))
         mystruct -> positions1[i] = a; 
         mystruct -> positons2[i] = b; 
         mystruct -> symbols[i] = c;   
         strcpy((mystruct -> names[i]), e); 
         mystruct -> args[i] = d; 
         i++; 
    }
}
```

When I print a, b, c, d, e on each iteration, they appear correct. If I do,

```
printf("%d %d %c %s %c\n", (mystruct-> positions1[i]), (mystruct -> positions2[i]), 
(mystruct->symbols[i]), (mystruct -> names[i]), (mystruct -> args[i])
```

It doesn't seem to have read the values into my structure. What am I doing wrong with my indexing?

EDIT: I originally had my final printf statement at the end of the function with fgets and sscanf. I moved it to main and it works, I'm not sure why it didn't have the values straight after the assignment however.

Comment: Where did you put the `printf` for the `mystruct` output?

Comment: Where is `mystruct` allocated in all of this? Please post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that reproduces the problem, along with a sample input file with a few sample rows and the *desired* console output.

Comment: `sscanf(buffer, "%d %d %c %s %c", &a, &b, &c, e, &d)` should be `sscanf(buffer, "%d %d %c %s %c", &a, &b, &c, e, &d) == 5`.